# Fraction Simplification -Actionscript 3

Tags: loops, actionscript-3, greatest-common-divisor

I'm fairly new at ActionScript 3, and I was attempting to create a program that simplifies fractions. I'm fairly certain that there is an error in regards to the implementation of the loop within the 'gcd' function, however no errors pop-up (for syntax or otherwise), and the logic seems to make sense. However, when I input the numerator and denominator, nothing seems to happen. Please advise. Thanks!

Here's what I've gotten done so far:

```
//add the click listener to a new function
btnDetermine.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

var no1:Number = Number(txtinno1.text);
var no2:Number = Number(txtinno2.text);
var i:Number;
var trueFalse:Boolean;

function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {

    //call the gcd function
    gcd(no1, no2);
}


function gcd(no1:Number, no2:Number):void {
    for (i = 2; (i < no1) && (i < no2) && (trueFalse == false); i++) {
        if (no1 % i == 0 && no2 % i == 0) {
            trueFalse = true;
            no1 = no1/i;
            no2 = no2/i;
            lblGCD.text = no1 + "/" + no2;
        }   
        else if (no1 == i || no2 == i) {
            lblGCD.text = no1 + "/" + no2;
        } 
        else {
            lblGCD.text = "Invalid!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because you read the values on start (which is before you input the values you want) rather than inside the click handler.

Comment: I'm not so sure I follow. When you click the button, it reads the text that's already been written to assign to the no1 and no2 variables which have the scope of only the clickHandler (if there is any text, but for this scenario, we'll assume that there is already valid input, because it is entered before I press the button). So as it executes the gcd function, the numbers are processed and printed to the label as text, is it not? This is why I'm fairly certain that the initial variables aren't the issue.

Comment: When the code runs, TextInputs are empty, right? At that point no1 and no2 are defined and given an empty value. They are not updated when you type something to the TextInput becouse they are not tied together that way. Like Organis said, you should catch the values inside the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
btnDetermine.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

var no1:Number;
var no2:Number;

function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    //this way it updates everytime you click
    no1 = Number(txtinno1.text);
    no2 = Number(txtinno2.text);

    //call the gcd function
    gcd(no1, no2);
}
```

When you define the variables, it does not automatically updates itself whenever the textfield updates. You will need to update the variable yourself. In your case, you set them outside of click function upon initialisation, at that point the text field is empty thus your number would be *null*. Since you will need it for your gcd function when the user clicks on *btnDetermine*, you can read the textfield values upon click and define them in that same function. Thus updating the variable when you need them.